# Wavefunction interpretations in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wavefunction, fourier-transform, probability

From *two-slit electron-interference experiment* we can infer that there is a wave $\psi(x,t)$ that can be associated with electron. The amplitude at some point is the sum of amplitudes
reaching that point and the intensity is $|\text{Amplitude}|^2=|\psi(x,t)|^2$. Intensity can naturally be interpreted as probability density for finding electron at location $x$ at any given time.

Then we know from Fourier theory that any smooth wave $\psi(x,t)$ that vanishes at infinity can be given in a following form: $$\psi(x,t)=\int _{-\infty} ^\infty \hat{\psi}(k,t)e^{ikx}dk.$$

We also know from Parseval's identy that $$\int _{-\infty} ^\infty |\psi(x,t)|^2dx=\int _{-\infty} ^\infty |\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2dk=1.$$

Now my question is that can we infer that $|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$ is a density function for momentum without resorting to Schrödinger equation? Is there any experiment that we can use to conclude?

Secondly, we can construct wave $\psi(x,t)$ in a sense of energy: $$\psi(x,t)=\int _{-\infty} ^\infty \hat{\psi}(x,\omega)e^{-i\omega t}d\omega.$$

How easy it is to "see" that $|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$ is a density function for energy?

Reason for my question is that if we have to those probability densities, then it would be easy to derive Schrödinger equation from one-dimensional *fundamental lemma of calculus of variations*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29140/discussion-on-question-by-juho-wavefunction-interpretations-in-qm).

Answer (score 1):

> Now I just begin with double-slit experiment and then conclude that there is a probability wave for electron

This is wrong. Firstly, the wave function is defined on configuration space, it isn't a wave in space. And secondly, it isn't using probability the way a mathematics textbook on probability uses the word probability. So it isn't a wave in space, and it isn't a probability. A wave function is one (of many) possible mathematical descriptions of a physical system.

> Now my question is that can we infer that $|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$ is a density function for momentum without resorting to Schrödinger equation?

We can't infer it because it isn't true. It is not the case that $|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$ is a probability density for momentum (or for wave number) and that $|{\psi}(x,t)|^2$ is a probability density for position.

In particular, there isn't a sample space on which two random variables (position and momentum) are defined and for which the values of both variables are determined by a region in the sample space, which is then unaffected by an observation/measurement. To do so would fundamentally deny the fact that the operators don't commute.

What we have sounds very similar but is different. We have a state. If you prepared many systems with that same state and measured position for some of them then the frequency of getting results within a region of width $\Delta x$ and containing some $x_0$ would approach $|{\psi}(x_0,t)|^2\Delta x$ as the number sampled gets large and $\Delta x$ gets small. This is different than a random variable on a sample space having a probability for different results. But for those states where you choose to measure the system you could make such a sample space.

Similarly, If you took those many systems with that same state and took the ones that you did **not** measure position on. Then if you "measure" momentum on those systems the frequency of getting results within a region of width $\Delta k$ and containing some $k_0$ would approach $|\hat{\psi}(k_0,t)|^2\Delta k$ as the number sampled gets large and $\Delta k$ gets small. This is different than a random variable on a sample space having a probability for different results. But for those states where you choose to measure the system you could make such a sample space.

So to be clear. If you pick up a text on probability they will start with a sample space, then have random variables and probabilities and then you do experiments. Here, you can't get a sample space until after you say what experiment you are going to do.  It might not seem very different, but when you do something even slightly different than what a mathematician assumed you were going to do, then their conclusions can't necessarily be applied.

So back to physics. You have a state, which is a mathematical description of the physical system. You have $|{\psi}(x,t)|^2$ which can be used to tell you the relative frequency of getting results of two different positions **amongst the many identically prepared systems of which you choose to measure position.** And you have $|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$ which can be used to tell you the relative frequency of getting results of two different momentums **amongst the many identically prepared systems of which you choose to measure momentum.** so you have three mathematical descriptions of three different things. Two describe frequencies of (different and incompatible) experimental outcomes, one one describes the physical system.

If you tried to get a joint probability distribution for position and momentum, you'd have to use a Wigner type distribution which would be negative in some regions of the 6d position-momentum phase space but when you integrate out all the positions from the Wigner distribution you get $|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$ and when you integrate out all the momentums from the Wigner distribution you get $|{\psi}(x,t)|^2.$ And the integrating is just the standard way of getting a marginal from a joint distribution, except of course this distribution is not nonnegative

So the reality is you merely get frequencies of different results for different experiments and doing the experiments changes things. And one distribution ($|{\psi}(x,t)|^2$ or $|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$) doesn't tell you the other one 
($|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$ or $|{\psi}(x,t)|^2$).

When you have the state, you have described the system completely, and can thus get the frequencies of any experiment whatsoever. Knowing the frequencies of one type of experimental setup is not enough information to tell you about different experimental setups.

> Is there any experiment that we can use to conclude?

No. There are states with different momentum distributions that have the same position distribution, so knowing the latter cannot possibly tell us the former.

> If $|\psi(x,t)|^2$ is not a probability density for position and $|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$ for momentum, then I will burn few of my QM texbooks. This must be that "quantum weirdness"

You use it in a similar manner in some situations. For instance to get the frequencies of certain results in repeated experiments. But there is no nonnegative joint distribution that has marginals like that.

Your textbooks use the word probability because they don't want to cover how to relate a frequency to averages and all that over again. It just isn't a probability space until after you select the experiment. And they do mention non commutativity, and they probably do say that that it is only a probability distribution for a fixed measurement. You just have to read carefully. And there just is no joint distribution and knowing the distribution of one experiment doesn't tell you the distribution for a different experiment.

Comment: That, Sir, is a very fine explanation. I wish I had your clarity.

Comment: If $|\psi(x,t)|^2$ is not a probability density for position and $|\hat{\psi}(k,t)|^2$ for momentum, then I will burn few of my QM texbooks. This must be that "quantum weirdness"  :D

Comment: @Juho You use it in a similar manner in some situations. For instance to get the frequencies of certain results in repeated experiments. But there is no nonnegative joint distribution that has marginals like that.

Comment: @Juho Your textbooks use the word probability because they don't want to cover how to relate a frequency to averages and all that over again. It just isn't a probability space until after you select the experiment. And they do mention non commutativity, and they probably do say that that it is only a probability distribution for a fixed measurement. You just have to read carefully. And there just is no joint distribution and knowing the distribution of one experiment doesn't tell you the distribution for a different experiment.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering. BTW: I found one online reference, see page 11. http://www.math.lmu.de/~lerdos/WS08/QM/lossstabmath.pdf

Comment: @Juho In that text they have to say "with respect to probability distribution [...]" all the time because they can't just start with a sample space they have explicitly say which probability distribution they are using. And really they should use a totally different probability distribution for each observable (or for each maximal commuting set of observables). For just an expectation value there are sometimes alternatives where you can use the wrong distribution in a particular way that still gives the correct answer. This doesn't however, make your question any less vague. I tried my best.

Comment: @Juho If you want yo derive a distribution for momentum you'd have to be totally clear and explicit about what you want to derive it from. And a probability distribution for positions won't be enough, since different momentum distributions can have the same position distribution.

Comment: @Timaeus: But if $\psi$ contais *all* the information of the system, then should it also contain the information for momentum distribution?

Comment: @Juho This is why if you want a derivation you should learn to be clear and explicitly say what you want to derive something from. You can compute both distributions from $\psi$ or from $\hat\psi.$ but you can't derive $|\psi(x)|^2$ from $|\hat\psi|^2$ or vice versa. And just having a functions doesn't tell you why you get other distributions, but the Schrödinger equation does tell you why those functions are the distributions. So the Schrödinger equation and the wavefunction do tell you everything. But one mere probability distribution doesn't tell you enough to get another.

Comment: @Timaeus: My aim was *not* to derive $\hat{\psi}$  from $|\psi|^2$ (no bijection). My question was that is there a way to understand $\hat{\psi}$ for momentum as we understand $\psi$ for position, without Schrödinger equation.

Comment: @Juho The Schrödinger equation tells you how things change in time. So when you apply it to your state and to your measurement device it tells you what results you get and the rate you get them. It tells you everything. Nothing else does. You can use the Schrödinger equation to derive the frequency of position measurements or the frequency of momentum measurements. Or you can have someone else tell you what it would say and use that. This is what $|\psi|^2$ and $|\hat\psi|^2$ do. The absolute reason they work are because of the Schrödinger equation because experiments take time.

Comment: @Juho And the Schrödinger equation says how things change in time, so it says how measurements go.